# Show/hide div based on user click?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am attempting to show/hide certain divs after a user clicks a div inside a sidebar on a google api map.  The divs are set up as:

```
<div id="Map">
    <div id="sidebarContainer">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="level1">
                <div class="level 2 primary [name of distributor]" id="[name of distributor]">
                [text data about the distributor in cased in some divs]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then for the subsidiaries:

```
<div class="level1">
<div class="level 2 subsidiary [name of distributor]" id="[name of distributor]" style="display:none">
```

My goal is that when a user clicks on a primary div, that it will show all the subsidiary divs.  The primary and subsidiary divs are on the 'same' level in the structure, just didn't classes depending on the distributor.  I have tried this javascript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(
    document.getElementsByClassName('level 2 primary ' + listingInfo.PARTY_NAME),
    'click',
    function() {
        console.log(listingInfo.PARTY_NAME + ' INSIDE THE CLICKY CLICKY');
        document.getElementsByClassName(listingInfo.PARTY_NAME)
            .style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
);
```

Where `listingInfo.PARTY_NAME = [name of the distributor]`.

I have also tried doing the listener on the level 1 div, but that did not seem to work.  I haven't been able to get my log message to appear, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend JQuery for this http://api.jquery.com/hide/. Is there any reason you can't use JQuery?

Comment: I don't think so. Ill investigate.  But I thought doing show/hide still takes layout space even if it isn't currently shown?

Comment: It shouldn't. At least I've never experienced it taking up space when using together with Bootstrap.

Comment: Would be much better if you could create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: can we see the full html structure that is relevant to this question? (you posted snippets, can we we see what it looks like in relation to each other)

Comment: sure. Ill make the edit.

Comment: let me know if that helps. It's hard cause I'm trying to edit someone else's code written years ago.

Comment: You don't need javascript for that, just some HTML and CSS, using checkboxes. google it

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="level 2 subsidiary [name of distributor]" id="[name of distributor]" style="display:none">`

In above line of your code `class` name is `level 2 subsidiary [name of distributor]` which contains space so it means that div has different class named `level`, `2`. So your code will not work as you intended.

Try to change class name with signle word.